# Unable to get computed value with After Insert trigger

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, triggers

I'm using the `FileTables` feature and have setup a trigger to populate a `FileProperties` table whenever a file is copied to the SQL Server file share.

I'm trying to grab the file size (`cached_file_size`), and I get a value of zero. I set up the trigger the same way a standard `FileTable` does using `DATALENTGH(file_stream)`. The code below is using the inserted tables' `file_stream`:

```
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[FileTable_Insert_Trigger] 
ON [dbo].[Files]
AFTER INSERT
AS 
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    DECLARE @s_id UNIQUEIDENTIFIER,
            @fs VARBINARY(MAX),
            @nm NVARCHAR(255),
            @fp NVARCHAR(MAX),
            @cfs BIGINT,
            @ft NVARCHAR(255);
 
    SELECT @s_id = ins.stream_id FROM inserted ins;
    SELECT @fs = ins.file_stream FROM inserted ins;
    SELECT @nm = ins.name FROM inserted ins;
    SELECT @fp = ins.file_stream.GetFileNamespacePath() FROM inserted ins;  
    SELECT @ft = ins.file_type FROM inserted ins;
    SELECT @cfs = DATALENGTH(@fs);

    INSERT INTO [FileProperties] (stream_id, [name], filepath, file_type,
                                  cached_file_size, DateAdded, UserID)
    VALUES (@s_id, @nm, @fp, @ft,
            @cfs, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, 1);
END
```

I've also tried grabbing the computed value directly from the `FileTable`:

```
SELECT @cfs = Files_1.cached_file_size 
FROM [dbo].Files AS Files_1 
WHERE Files_1.stream_id = @s_id;
```

Still getting zero. What am I missing here? Thank you.

[EDIT] I tried playing around with getting the `DATALENGTH` of other values such as the `name (@nm)` and `stream_id (@s_id)` and I do get the values correctly.

Comment: For a start, you've made a trigger 101 mistake in assuming that `Inserted` always contains a single row - it doesn't, it could contain 0-N. Why are you transferring the values from `Inserted` to variables, then back to a table? Just insert into your table directly from Inserted.

Comment: @DaleK - It works fine with adding multiple files as is, however, I'm still learning and building the trigger and would like to figure out this issue before I refine the trigger.  I should also add I'm a novice with TSQL.

Comment: It only works fine because you are only adding a single file at a time... you need to get the basics right because it might resolve the issue you are facing at the same time. And you didn't answer my second point.

Comment: I'm using variables because the tutorial I found did it this way.

Comment: Good, well don't :) SQL is a set based language... you should aim for set based operations wherever possible. i.e. `insert into MyTable (Cols) select cols from Inserted`.

Comment: Thanks.  I'll keep that in mind.  Also, when I copy multiple files at the same time, the trigger fires for each file and I get a separate entries as expected.

Comment: Thats down to how the insert happens, but any insert, can in principle, insert multiple (or zero) rows, and you should always write your triggers to handle that. TBH you should avoid using triggers in the first place most of the time.

Comment: I highly recommend supplementing anything your learn from a tutorial with the [official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/triggers/use-the-inserted-and-deleted-tables?view=sql-server-ver15)

Comment: Aside: If you ever do need to get several values into variables from a single row you can use a single statement, e.g. `select @Foo = Foo, @Bar = Bar, @BarLength = DataLength( Bar ) from LotsaRows where SomethingUnique = @KeyValue;`. It's not appropriate in your trigger, but good to know about.

Comment: I'm not a fan of triggers but this could easily be turned into a set based operation by simply getting rid of all those pointless variables. Just do an insert with a select statement. Your trigger is mountains simpler AND it will handle any number of rows being inserted.